# How to retrieve multi-value Taxonomy Field from term store SharePoint online

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, csom, sharepoint-jsom

I am trying to retrieve terms from term store using JavaScript, it work just a fine with this code: 
Get the label of single taxonomy field:

```
var fieldValue = item.get_item("FieldName");
var fieldLabel = fieldValue.Label;
```

I have one issue to retrieve labels of a multi-value Taxonomy Field?
I've tried this

```
var fieldValue = item.get_item("FieldName");
var taxEnumerator = fieldValue.getEnumerator();
while(taxEnumerator.moveNext()){
    var currentTerm = taxEnumerator.get_current();
    var label = currentTerm.Label;
    // do something with the label here
}
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: @Thriggle : do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you are getting this error since `sp.taxonomy.js` library has not been loaded and in that case taxonomy field value is returned as "lightweight" object (**not** of [SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValueCollection object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn312524.aspx) type).

**Option 1 (recommended): getting getting multiple taxonomy field values with `sp.taxonomy` library**

First of all, I would recommend this approach since `SP.Taxonomy` namespace provides not only a standard way for dealing with taxonomy field values but also a way of working with Managed Metadata API via JSOM.

The following example shows how to:

- ensure sp.taxonomy.js library has been loaded
- get *multiple* taxonomy field value which represents
  [SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValueCollection object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn312524.aspx)

Example:

```
SP.SOD.registerSod('sp.taxonomy.js', SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl('sp.taxonomy.js'));   
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.taxonomy.js', 'SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession', function () { 

var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
var item = list.getItemById(itemId);
ctx.load(item);

ctx.executeQueryAsync(
   function(){

      var fieldVal = item.get_item(fieldName); 

      for(var i = 0; i < fieldVal.get_count(); i++) {
         var label = fieldVal.get_item(i).get_label();
         var guid = fieldVal.get_item(i).get_termGuid();
         //...
      }       
   },
   function(sender,args){
       console.log(args.get_message());
   });


});
```

**Option 2: getting multiple taxonomy field values *without* `sp.taxonomy.js` library loaded**

When `sp.taxonomy` library is **not** loaded, taxonomy field value could still be retrieved via `_Child_Items_` property as demonstrated below:

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
var item = list.getItemById(itemId);
ctx.load(item);

ctx.executeQueryAsync(
   function(){

      var fieldVal = item.get_item(fieldName)._Child_Items_; 
      for(var i = 0; i < fieldVal.length; i++) {
         var label = fieldVal[i].Label;
         var guid = fieldVal[i].TermGuid;
         //...
      }       
   },
   function(sender,args){
       console.log(args.get_message());
   });
```